# Error in Android Faceebook SSO Login

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

By following the Facebook SDK 3.0 Document for android and developed sample app, but still am getting an error, "'app_name' is miss configured for Facebook login."

I registered my app on fb too, [image]

fb hash key is generated with the help of openssl command.

Did I missed anything here. Please guide me. I can't do login with default fb application.

I do follow this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

and create this project, even though getting this error.

Comment: i think u used same name in fb and facebook sdk3.0 so, there might be problem of misconfigured..just try to remove app from fb and then try

Comment: Thanks Mehul, but didn't get u exactly. I tried with 2 different fb account. And getting the same error.

Comment: what is your app name..and if possible change your app name without giving spaces to it..and try it

Comment: @MehulRanpara, I gave different names and tried also, suppose app name is Facebook, my package name is com.facebook then may be a problem occurs. So I tried different name FacebookTest and same package name. Even though getting the same problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me what to write in Package Name and Class Name in above image?

Comment: in mobile do you have facebook app already?

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys, Ya I have.

Comment: because of that only you are getting SSO issue.. you need to change the some conditions in faceebook sdk to work api alone .. without interacting into the facebook app.

Comment: you are using old facebook sdk or new facebook sdk?

Comment: using new SDK 3.0, without interrupting the facebook app, my code is working , that I checked earlier but I want to integrate default fb app

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay You means If Default Facebook application is installed on your device at that time the fb login dialog is not opened, Am I Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please check this, I found the solution on facebook developer and solved my issue.](http://rahulupadhyay.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/facebook-sso/)

Answer (score 0):

Error:'app_name' is miss configured. This error shows that `you are not signing the app with the key, whose hashKey is on facebook`. Try creating hashKey again, Also add your debug.keystore's key hash into facebook. You can add multiple key hashes on facebook. (A newly added key hash can take few minutes to take effect)